# "Estimated Number of Executions" is inflated

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have a situation where a slower query plan is being chosen instead of a faster one due to, I believe, some incorrect estimates. However, I can't figure out where the incorrect estimates are coming from. Shown below is the faster plan which is not chosen because of the estimated cost of 123 for the Index Seek. In reality the cost isn't nearly so high as you can see from the difference between Actual and Estimated Number of Executions. My understanding is that the number of executions is driven by the number of rows from the top side of the nested loop. As you can see, the estimated number of rows there is 4878, which is pretty close to actual. But the estimated number of executions for the bottom input is 61110, which is way off. FWIW, I've updated statistics on all tables with full scan, and the 1.22 Estimated Rows is correct (for each execution).

Where is that 61110 number coming from and is there any way to fix it?

The query looks like this:

```
    SELECT
        Top.Pk
    FROM
        Top
        LEFT JOIN Bottom ON Bottom.Fk = Top.Pk
    WHERE
        Top.Date < GETUTCDATE()
        AND Bottom.Fk IS NULL
```

[image: Estimated Number of Executions wrong]

Comment: I forgot to mention, the top table is an indexed view in case that matters.

Comment: You'll need to supply more details on your actual queries and tables. Statistics are only one aspect of cardinality estimates. Next on the list would be what your search and join conditions actually are. A common problem is to have join conditions that the optimizer can't correlate with actual table contents, so you get off-the-cuff estimates based solely on the table size of how many rows will match. Another problem is a table with very non-homogeneous content where there really might be 60.000 resulting rows on particular matches, for all the optimizer knows.

Comment: In this case it's joining on a GUID. The PK in the top table to a FK in the bottom. That is the only predicate of the seek. Regarding homogeneous, I thought that was the whole point of the statistics? Regardless, the Estimated Number of Rows is correct (there are not 60,000 resulting rows on a particular match, there are 1.22). The issue is the Estimated Number of Executions, which, I thought, is driven by the top input (according to the description of nested loops in the screenshot).

Comment: "Regarding homogeneous, I thought that was the whole point of the statistics?" Yes, but you have to understand that if (say) you have one row with 10.000 corresponding rows in another table, and one with 2, the optimizer still cannot know *in advance* what case(s) your query will happen to hit, even with perfect statistics. Plans still have to be compiled in advance and cannot be based on what data will *actually* flow through. You are right that the 1.22302 estimate seems to be more or less correct when extrapolated to the actual result, however, so that would not be the issue.

Comment: I've added the query. I get what you're saying regarding homogeneous data, but that's not the case here. The problem isn't that the statistics are inflated (I don't believe). That would affect Estimated Number of Rows. In this case, Estimated Number of Rows is correct and lines up nicely with the actual: Actual Executions (4813) * Estimated Number of Rows (1.22) ~= Actual Number of Rows (5205). The problem is the Estimated Number of *Executions*, which I can't figure out where that's coming from. Presumably it would come from the Esitmated Number of Rows from the top.

Comment: Does the estimate change if you replace `GETUTCDATE()` with a constant? (It shouldn't, since actual ~ estimated already.) How about if you add `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)`? (I always get confused about what numbers the optimizer changes when parallel plans are involved.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127556/discussion-between-james-brantly-and-jeroen-mostert).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I still don't fully understand what the execution plan is showing us here, as it turns out this particular instance of the problem can be fixed by specifying [`WITH (NOEXPAND)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187373) on the indexed view, forcing the optimizer to consider the index on the indexed view (which I thought it was doing already from the execution plan, but apparently not).